# How to add and resolve URL as we do with host name after adding it in /etc/hosts file

Tags: http, url, dns, localhost, host

I have a web app running on machine with ip : 172.10.10.10.

The basic API call exposed by this app is : GET - http://172.10.10.10 
and it will return a response as OK.

On another machine I added an entry in **/etc/hosts** file as below.

**172.10.10.10 webserver1.com**

With this the ping command is resolved successfully. e.g. : ping webserver1.com

Now I want to resolve the curl command as well.

e.g. : curl http://webserver1.com

Result : curl: (6) Could not resolve host: webserver1.com

How to achieve this for curl command with http url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup a DNS server and point your IP in /etc/resolv.conf
There are many options out there in marker ( paid / free ) for a Local DSN Server dockerized and non-dockerized too.